# datetime value in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I updated the datetime to the datebase. It's 5/2/2012. But when I want to show this value from that database into a textbox it will show me : 05/02/2012.

Please help me to solve this problem. I want to show it's value into the textbox like the format has been updated : 5/2/2010

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you retrieving the date from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing that the best way is saving datetime into the database as a string. then after retrieving the string I can convert that to datetime. and it will show the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data as a `DateTime` object, then you can format its output using its `ToString(string)` overload with the format string "d/M/yyyy" or any other format as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'
+CAST(DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'
+CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Comment: Ouch.  Just query the date and format in code.  You should not be doing UI presentation work in a query (Data Layer / Service Layer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Textbox1.Text=datevalue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ToString("d/M/yyyy")` to give desired format.

If you can show me your code then I can help you more.

Comment: Can't use string after Tostring

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` while assigning the value.
If your textbox is `Textbox1` and your date value is stored in `DateTime` object **datevalue** then you should do it like this.

`Textbox1.Text=datevalue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Answer (score 0):

When you store this data into sql server as datetime type then the original format is lost.  However, if you want to show the data without leading 0's then you can do this for your textbox.

mytextbox.Text = dt.Month.ToString().TrimStart('0') + "/" + dt.Day.ToString().TrimStart('0') + "/" + dt.Year.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

It's generally poor practice to go mucking with your data with a complex query or pre-format the data before reaching your application as you lose flexibility with the results.

The data coming from SQL is properly formatted as a generic DateTime stamp - allow the application to massage it for display purposes, as @Chris-Sinclair suggests with the link to examples.

The best aproach, if using WPF, is to allow the UI element to format the text as it sees fit, that way the content of your class instances remains unmodified. It's still a DateTime object so you can do DateTime "math" or other manupiations without losing the full value.

Here is an example from [elegantcode.com](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/) where the WPF UI element determines it's format:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}}" />
```

For your speficif purpose the correct line would read

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt}}" />
```